# Closed immersion of affine schemes equivalent to surjection on rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

For any morphism of schemes $f:Y\to X$, we say that $f$ is a *closed immersion* if:

- $|Y|$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $|X|$,
- $f^\#: \mathcal{O}_{X}\to f_*\mathcal{O}_{Y}$ is surjective on stalks.

Let us specialize to $f: \text{Spec}(B)\to \text{Spec}(A)$. Then I want to show that

> $f$ is a closed immersion if and only if $A\to B$ is surjective.

I am able to show the converse. But I am a bit lost on showing the forward direction. Suppose $f$ is a closed immersion. My plan is to show that $A_{\mathfrak{p}}\to B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is surjective for all $\mathfrak{p}\in\text{Spec}(A)$ as $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$-modules, thus implying the surjectivity of $A\to B$.

Taking $\mathfrak{p}\in \text{Spec}(A)$ (and let us assume $\mathfrak{q}=f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ for now), and localizing the sheaf map, we get
$$ f^\#_{\mathfrak{p}}: A_\mathfrak{p}=\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(A),\mathfrak{p}}\to (f_*\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(B)})_{\mathfrak{p}} = \mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(B),\mathfrak{q}} = B_\mathfrak{q}. $$
So this "localization" is not really compatible with the one I want as modules. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the localization map is precisely localization as modules:
$$ (f_*\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(B)})_\mathfrak{p} =\varinjlim_{\mathfrak{p}\in U} \mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(B)}(f^{-1}U)= \varinjlim_{t\notin \mathfrak{p}} \mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(B)}(f^{-1}D_X(t)) = \varinjlim_{t\notin \mathfrak{p}} \mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(B)}(D_Y(f^\#t)) = B_\mathfrak{p}. $$
Here $D_X(\bullet)$ and $D_Y(\bullet)$ are basic open sets. This immediately implies the global sections $f^\#:A\to B$ is injective. So at least for morphisms between affine schemes, I believe that the first topological condition is redundant.

See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649629/hartshorne-exercise-ii-2-18d) for the same conclusion.